# Removing punctuation from given string by retaining ZERO in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove punctuations from a given string in perl using following command

```
      perl -le '$x=19.10 ; $x=~s/[[:punct:]]//g; print $x'
```

This gives output as : 191

It removes trailing 0 from the input. I want to retain it too.

For other numbers its successfully returns all the values like:

```
      perl -le '$x=19.11 ; $x=~s/[[:punct:]]//g; print $x'
```

This gives output as : 1911

How do I retain the trailing 0 in the first case?

Comment: You need to assign a string, not a number. Numbers don't remember how they were typed as literals.

Comment: That means that already `$x` doesn't know of zeros (it's `19.1`, so to say) so further processing can't help. How do these numbers (or strings) come into the program/variables?  I guess they're  not assigned as literals like in this example

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew You closed this as a dup of a Q&A saying to use `s/[[:punct:]]//g`, which is what the OP is already using...

Comment: The number 19.10 is the same as 19.100, same as 19.1 or 19.10000. The compiler does not know how many zeros you want if it is a number. If the zeros are important, use a string or format the number to a string.

Answer (score 3):

You assigned the number `19.10000000000000142108547152020037174224854` (the closest floating point number to nineteen and one-tenth) to `$x`. You then proceeded to stringify that number, giving the string `19.1`. From that, you removed the `.` giving `191`.

You could use

```perl
my $x = "19.10"; $x =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
```

or

```perl
my $x = 19.10; $x *= 100;
```